# How to publish WPF application added to Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: wpf

I have added WPF application to Xamarin.Forms and I have published that app. After publishing done, the application was installed with setup.exe but the application is not loading.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This seems like not enough details to help you with your issue. Can you please elaborate what you mean by "not" loading, add some code snippets if relevant and in general expand on your question?

Comment: After running setup.exe  the application is not responsive i.e(it is closing with in 2 seconds  automatically and also unable to edit text in entry)

Comment: It look slike you have an inifinite loop in your application, but still, please provide more details to help us, we don't sit in your head :) Please edit your question and include the code that is executed at application startup (do not include all of your code, just the relevant pieces).

Comment: Here the application is login page while debugging it is working fine but, the problem is after publishing it is not responding  can anyone please gude me to resolve it .Thank you